# Slanted Column Headers

Tags: html, css, sass

I want to build a table with slanted column headers as shown in the image below.[image]

But I am not able to align the slanted header div with actual column and the text is overflowing the column header. [here](https://jsfiddle.net/SSV0811/b1mrksou/) is the link to my code.

My question is how do we align the slanted column header with the column below it and contain the text within it ?

Here is my code below

```
<table>
<tr>
<td> 
    <div class="outerDiv"> 
      <div class="innerDiv">This is first column header </div>
    </div> 
</td> 
<td> 
    <div class="outerDiv"> 
      <div class="innerDiv">This is second column header</div> 
    </div>     
</td> 
<td> 
    <div class="outerDiv"> 
      <div class="innerDiv">This is third column header</div>  
    </div>
</td> 
</tr>
  <tr> <td> 1 </td> <td> 2 </td> <td> 3 </td> </tr>
  <tr> <td> 4 </td> <td> 5 </td> <td> 6 </td> </tr>
  <tr> <td> 7 </td> <td> 8 </td> <td> 9 </td> </tr>
  <tr> <td> 10 </td> <td> 11 </td> <td> 12 </td> </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.outerDiv {
background: grey;
height: 200px;
width: 100px;
border: 1px solid black;
transform: skew(-30deg);
}

body, html {
height: 100%;
}

.innerDiv{
transform:skew(45deg);
writing-mode: vertical-lr;
}

body {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
}

table {
border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, td, th {
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another attempt. I changed the header cells to `th`. I added a translateX to get it to line up better. For the inside dev I reversed skewed it so the text didn't look funny and then rotated the container so it was still at a slant following the container. Also added some positioning to get it to look right.

https://jsfiddle.net/b1mrksou/3/

The CSS I added:

```
* {
  box-sixing: border-box;
}

.outerDiv {
  background: grey;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-left: 0;
  transform: skew(-30deg) translateX(58%);
}

th:first-child .outerDiv {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

.innerDiv {
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  height: 85px;
  bottom: -34%;
  left: 10px;
  transform: skew(30deg) rotate(-60deg);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: This helps, but when you have larger text in the column headers the text-overflows. https://jsfiddle.net/SSV0811/b1mrksou/5/

Comment: Oh ok, I was going off of the numbers from your original code and thought it was fixed sizing (100 x 200). What are you looking for it to do? Grow taller? Grow wider?

Comment: No, the height of the column header should be constant, but width to be adjusted according the the content, the column should grow wider with long text.

Comment: Can we grow this wider ?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like the best solution I could come up with.  http://jsbin.com/yecevosunu

```
<!doctype html><style>
table { border-collapse: collapse;}
td {border: 1px solid #000;}
</style><table class=tilttable>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>word</th>
      <th>words and more and more words</th>
      <th>two<br>words</th>
      <th>word</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>data</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script>
function toDegrees (angle) {return angle * (180 / Math.PI);}
function toRadians (angle) {return angle * (Math.PI / 180);}

onload=function(){

var tilttables = document.getElementsByClassName('tilttable');

[].forEach.call(tilttables[0].rows[0].cells
, function (i) {
  i.style.verticalAlign = "bottom";
  i.innerHTML = "<div><div>" + i.innerHTML + "</div></div>";
  i.firstChild.firstChild.setAttribute('style',"transform-origin:top left;transform: rotate(-45deg);");
  tilt(i.firstChild.firstChild);
});

}
function tilt(d){
  var w = d.clientWidth;
  var h = d.clientHeight;

  d.parentElement.style.width = h*Math.cos(toRadians(45))+"px";
  d.style.whiteSpace="nowrap";
  d.parentElement.style.paddingTop = w*Math.sin(toRadians(45))+"px";
  d.parentElement.style.height = h*Math.sin(toRadians(45))+"px";
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use `writing-mode`, a pseudo element, `transform` and some tunning with `margin`s:

```css
table {
  margin-right: 6em;
}

th {
  padding: 0;
  position: relative
}

th>div {
  white-space:nowrap;
  margin: -1em -2em -1em 6em;/* tune this to your needs, you might also see & update  transform-origin */
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  /* old Win safari */
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  writing-mode: tb-lr;
  transform: scale(-1, -1) rotate(45deg);
}

th:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border: solid;
  transform: skew(-45deg);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}

td {
  border: solid;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <div class="innerDiv"> first </div>
    </th>
    <th>
      <div class="innerDiv">This is second column header</div>
    </th>
    <th>
      <div class="innerDiv">This is third header</div>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 1 </td>
    <td> 2 </td>
    <td> 3 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 4 </td>
    <td> 5 </td>
    <td> 6 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 7 </td>
    <td> 8 </td>
    <td> 999999999999999 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 10 </td>
    <td> 11 </td>
    <td> 12 </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/xqdNGN